# hardhat configuration for multiple accounts in testnet

Tags: hardhat

How to add multiple accounts here for rinkeby testnet

```
  networks: {
    rinkeby: {
      url: process.env.RINKEBY_URL || "",
      accounts: process.env.RINKEBY_PRIVATE_KEY_0 !== undefined ? [process.env.RINKEBY_PRIVATE_KEY_0 ]:[],
    },
  },
```

I tried

```
accounts : [process.env.RINKEBY_PRIVATE_KEY_0, process.env.RINKEBY_PRIVATE_KEY_1]
```

But it gives error.

> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Answer (score 0):

Error appeave due to `process.env.RINKEBY_PRIVATE_KEY_0` (or `process.env.RINKEBY_PRIVATE_KEY_1`) can be undefined, but in accounts list must be only string type variables. You have to write:

```
accounts : [
  process.env.RINKEBY_PRIVATE_KEY_0 as string,
  process.env.RINKEBY_PRIVATE_KEY_1 as string
]
```